# What do angled brackets in a typedef statement mean?

Tags: c++, typedef

Can someone explain to me what is going on in this line (from dlib library)

```
typedef object_detector <scan_fhog_pyramid<pyramid_down<6>>> simple_object_detector
```

Are the angled brackets here like the angled brackets of `std::vector<int>` (ie. specifying a list/array)? Also, what is the `6`, I have no idea what that is.

Comment: Look and the definition of `object_detector`, `scan_fhog_pyramid`, and `pyramid_down`.  These are all templates

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they are like the angled brackets of `std::vector<int>`.

No, they have nothing to do with lists/arrays.

6 is a number.

Look up "templates" in your C++ book.